# How does a power hacksaw lift on the forward stroke?

Tags: mechanical-engineering, mechanisms

Hacksaw blades cut on the pull stroke (back into the machine) and are supposed to lift on the push stroke, all the DIY setups I have seen cut on both the pull and push stroke, i.e.

[image]

What type of setup would allow you lift ever so slightly on the push stroke? Alternatively, are power hacksaw blades bi-directional? All help appreciated.

Comment: Unless the blade has teeth pointing both ways the blade only cuts in one direction.

Comment: I don't think they do. I know I don't lift the saw on the backstroke. It would just getstuck in the gullet of the cut.

Answer (score 1):

If a power saw lifts on the non-cutting stroke, then this is usually achieved with an eccentric cam to lift the cutting arm a fraction.

Answer (score 0):

Noted that Q had not really been answered

Power hacksaws can be either push to cut or pull to cut but not both ways as the cut is determined by the set direction of the teeth. Most saws lift the blade slightly on the non cutting stroke. The cut direction is usually only one way or the other because the lift is setup for only one way.